# How to pass values between Vue sibling components, without using 'params'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently I have 2 components:

- Proyectos.vue
- Reuniones.vue

Where:

- **Proyectos**: it is the component that I show in the beginning of my App, where the list of projects is shown.
- **Reuniones**: it is the component where the list of meetings of a project is shown.

In the Proyectos component I make a `GET` request which returns me an array of objects, ie proyectos. With this list of projects I fill a table.

**Proyecto object structure:**

```
    {
        objetivo:"", 
        fecha: "",
        reuniones: [
        {
            titulo: "",
            fecha: ""
        },
        {
            titulo: "",
            fecha: ""
       }]
   }
```

For each table row I have a project javascript object which I want to send to the `Reuniones` component when I click on a button. Once in the `Reuniones` component, I will do certain actions, like iterate it.

[image]

### Decision not to use params

I'm looking for a way to not have to send the `Id` through the url and have to make a new `get` of the object. I want to use the object with which I already count from the Proyectos component.

### Attempt to use events

I tried to use events using `$emit` and `$on` but since the Reuniones component is not yet loaded, I can not hear of the event that I send from the Proyectos component.

Proyectos.vue:

```
projectSelected (project) {
     // I issue an event with the project object
     this.$root.$emit ('send', project)
     // I call the route 'reuniones' to load the Reuniones.vue component
     this.$router.push('reuniones')
}
```

Reuniones.vue

```
this.$root.$on('send', (data) => {
     console.log (data)
})
```

---

The behavior I'm looking for is to be able to use an object between components.

Comment: Passing data around to sibling components is messy. Ideally the component parent to both siblings should be the one which stores the list of projects and passes them down to both components. Data flow should be down, not sideways.

Comment: @DecadeMoon But how should I be controlling which component is shown? Currently I do it depending on the URL. If I use the App.vue component to be the father of those components, how am I going to switch between components?

Comment: You can still do it depending on the URL, but the App component will do all of the heavy lifting (storing the list of projects, the currently selected project, doing API calls, etc), then just pass down this data to the master and detail components for display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might consider the global state called eventBus, you can read about it [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

It will allow you to create make there methods for your get request and watch for changes on your .vue instances with computed properties or watchers

Comment: Yes, i tried that, is the section "Attempt to use events". But the Reuniones component is not yet loaded. When is executed $emit i load the other component with `this.$router.push('reuniones')`  this is why the `on` in that component does not know about change.